# New Google Play Console Order TIME in UTC

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

The "new" Google Play Console displays the purchase time for app purchases in the UTC time zone.  How do I get it to show the purchase time in the local time zone like in the "old" Google Play Console?  I can't find the setting if there is one.